# Years old iptables script breaks (-o option no longer exists?)

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, update, wireguard

I've had a script for a while that forwards a port through my Wireguard VPN. Recently, I tried using it and it returned:

```
Bad argument `wg0'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: ./wireguard_port_forward.sh <client IP> <server IP> <port> <interface>
# Example: ./wireguard_port_forward.sh 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 8080 ens3
# Script must be run as root

CLIENT=$1
SERVER=$2
PORT=$3
INTERFACE=$4

iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERFACE -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport $PORT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERFACE -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o $INTERFACE -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INTERFACE -p tcp --dport "$PORT" -j DNAT --to-destination "$CLIENT"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport "$PORT" -d "$CLIENT" -j SNAT --to-source "$SERVER"
netfilter-persistent save
```

Was the `-o` argument removed? I'm not very familiar with iptables and don't want to mess up my firewall rules by fiddling around too much.

Comment: The error says nothing about `-o`, but that the `wg0` is an invalid argument. Does the interface exist? Could it have been renamed?

Comment: I agree with Esa, looks for me that the wg0 interface is missing

Comment: The interface does indeed exist. If I run "iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERFACE -p tcp --syn --dport $PORT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT" (which does not contain -o), it says: `Bad argument `tcp'`

Comment: is it possible that the variable `$INTERFACE` is empty? This would mess up the order of the following arguments and lead to exactly your error messages.

Comment: Please run `export SHELLOPTS; set -x` before executing your script. The extended output should help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: hmmmm. You suspect a compatibility issue but aren't going to tell us anything about the version of iptables or the OS its running on.

Comment: It can only be what Gerald Schneider wrote: OP used the script without providing $4 (as in the scripts comment: the 4th parameter to give to the script) => -i -o wg0 : input interface `-o` followed by an unknown option `wg0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough parameters to the script. Therefore, `$INTERFACE` is empty and you get the `Bad argument` error. A script like this, especially when run as root, should validate the inputs and give an error before using them in the `iptables` commands. E.g.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -lt 4 ]; then
  echo "Usage: sudo $0 <client IP> <server IP> <port> <interface>"
  echo "Example: sudo $0 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 8080 ens3"
  exit 1
fi

if ! [ "$(id -u)" = 0 ]; then
  echo "Script must be run as root"
  exit 1
fi

CLIENT="$1"
SERVER="$2"
PORT="$3"
INTERFACE="$4"
WGIF="wg0"

function valid_ip()
{
  local ip="$1"
  local stat=1

  if [[ "$ip" =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    OIFS="$IFS"
    IFS='.'
    # shellcheck disable=SC2206
    ip=($ip)
    IFS="$OIFS"
    [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
      && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
      stat="$?"
  fi
  return "$stat"
}

errors=0

if ! valid_ip "$CLIENT" ; then
  echo "Invalid client IP: $CLIENT"
  ((errors=errors+1))
fi

if ! valid_ip "$SERVER" ; then
  echo "Invalid server IP: $SERVER"
  ((errors=errors+1))
fi

if ! [ "$PORT" -le 65535 ]; then
  echo "Invalid TCP port: $PORT"
  ((errors=errors+1))
fi

if ! [ "$PORT" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Invalid TCP port: $PORT"
  ((errors=errors+1))
fi

if ! ( ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' \
  | grep "$INTERFACE" > /dev/null ); then
  echo "Interface not found: $INTERFACE"
  ((errors=errors+1))
fi

if [ "$errors" -ge 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

set -e

iptables -A FORWARD -i "$INTERFACE" -o "$WGIF" -p tcp --syn \
  --dport "$PORT" -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i "$INTERFACE" -o "$WGIF" -m conntrack \
  --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i "$WGIF" -o "$INTERFACE" -m conntrack \
  --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i "$INTERFACE" -p tcp \
  --dport "$PORT" -j DNAT --to-destination "$CLIENT"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o "$WGIF" -p tcp --dport "$PORT" \
  -d "$CLIENT" -j SNAT --to-source "$SERVER"
netfilter-persistent save

echo "Successfully forwarded port $PORT from $CLIENT" \
  "to $SERVER on interface $INTERFACE."
```

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly stupid on my part. You were right, I wasn't providing enough arguments in my script and it was messing it up. Thank you for this version with input validation.